# Where can I find the documentation for the APIs, protocols, and formats that travel suppliers use to communicate with the Sabre Travel Network?

Tags: sabre

Where can I find the documentation for the APIs, protocols, and formats that travel suppliers (such as airlines, hotels, rental car companies, cruise lines, rail lines, tour operators, etc.) use to communicate with the Sabre Travel Network?

developer.sabre.com provides excellent documentation for the APIs, protocols, and formats that travel buyers such as travel agents, TMCs, OTAs, corporate travel buyers, etc. use to communicate with the Sabre Travel Network. However, I have not been able to find any documentation for the APIs, protocols, and formats that travel suppliers (such as airlines, hotels, rental car companies, cruise lines, rail lines, tour operators, etc.) use to communicate with the Sabre Travel Network? Where can I find this documentation?

For example, what APIs, protocols, formats, messages, etc. do travel suppliers use to receive and respond to requests for availability, pricing, booking, reservations, ticketing, etc. from the Sabre Travel Network? Where is the documentation for such APIs, protocols, formats, messages, etc.?